# Processing file before upload using ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

How would I process a file before it's uploaded using activestorage.  I need to be able to modify an svg file's content before it actually gets uploaded to S3.  Can't seem to find any callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this natively with ActiveStorage. It's the major drawback with using ActiveStorage.

As far as I know, the only way to modify an upload is to create a variant of the original upload after it is created...which creates a (completely different) variant image based on the image that was originally uploaded.

ActiveStorage is easy to setup but, after using it with a few applications, Carrierwave..etc seem like better options.

In addition, if you want to upload in a background job, ActiveStorage is a pain.

Comment: ActiveStorage isn't mature enough yet.  Last I checked you also can't distinguish from specific file types.  People can just upload any file type they want with no way to filter (through pure rails or ruby at least).

Comment: From what I read, 6.0 was supposed to solve this, or at least was on their road mad as a feature.  I'm sure it will end up beating carrierwave in the coming years.  I do like its simplicity and how fast it is