# ActiveStorage: How to validate content of file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I would like to read the content of a file that is to be uploaded in a custom validation. Is it possible?

So far, I've seen that it's possible to perform some validations on the file's metadata (extention, size...) but not on it's content. I've also seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57601702/processing-file-before-upload-using-activestorage) that's a bit similar, even though I don't want to modify the file. I just want to read it in a custom validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you can access the file being uploaded and simply read it in the validation.

For Example

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :resume
  
  validate :resume_contents

  private 
    def resume_contents
      return unless record.send(attribute).attached? && !record.attachment_changes['resume'].blank?
      file = record.attachment_changes['resume'].attachable
      if file.is_a?(ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile) && file.read =~ /bad content/i
        errors.add(:resume, :invalid, message: 'cannot contain bad content')
      end
    end
end
```

For a more in depth implementation you could refer to the `active_storage_validations` gem:

- [File Access](https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/active_storage_validations/blob/master/lib/active_storage_validations/processable_image_validator.rb#L19)
- [File Reading](https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/active_storage_validations/blob/master/lib/active_storage_validations/metadata.rb#L124)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but If `self.resume.is_a?(ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile)` returns `true`, it means that the file has already been uploaded. Since the file upload happens when the record is inserted, it's not possible to access the uploaded file is about to be created (in a validation).
If I tried to read the unread record, I get the following error:
```eval error: undefined method `read' for #<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x00000001170f0178```

Comment: @DavidB. updated based on a further code dive through the gem. While I have no where to actually validate this I would like to answer the questions you posed. "*If self.resume.is_a?(ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile) returns true, it means that the file has already been uploaded"* this is incorrect. The file has been uploaded via a form (e.g. multipart form data) this doe not mean it  has been uploaded to your data repository (i.e. S3)...

Comment: *"it's not possible to access the uploaded file is about to be created (in a validation)"* this is incorrect. The file data must be sent to the server so that it can even be uploaded so this information does exist on the server side and can be validated